# 8 bit adder design? Link two 4bit adders?

Tags: logic, 8-bit, gate

Ive created a 4bit adder design but I need an 8bit. Could I create two 4bit and link the outputs together through an AND gate?

My 4 bit adder:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao60s6dgtrnhal3/4bit%20adder.PNG

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Two half-adders become a full-adder. Why not a 4-bit half adder couple with another to make a full one?

Comment: Your four bit adder design already has carry in/carry out. I think those can be just linked together -- however, the propagation delay will be doubled.